# Implementing ArrayList in Java. Working on getUnique, addBefore and removeLast

Tags: java, android, arraylist

```
public class MyArrayList<T> implements MyList<T>{
    int num;        //number of things in the list
    T[] vals;       //to store the contents

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MyArrayList() {
        num = 0;
        vals = (T[]) new Object[3];
    }

    public int size() {  //returns number of things in the bag
        return num;
    }

    public T get(int index) {  //returns the indexth values
        if((index < 0) || (index >= num))
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        return vals[index];
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void add(T s) {  //adds s to the list
        if(num == vals.length) {  //if array is full, make it bigger
            T[] temp = (T[]) new Object[vals.length*2];
            for(int i=0; i < num; i++)
                temp[i] = vals[i];
            vals = temp;
        }
        vals[num] = s;
        num++;
    }

    public boolean contains(T s) {  //returns whether s is list
        for(int i=0; i < num; i++) {  //ending condition should be num
            if(vals[i].equals(s)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public T getUnique(){
        T distinct = null;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<vals.length; i++){
            distinct =  vals[i];
            for (int j = 0; j<vals.length; j++){
            if (vals[j] == vals[i]){
                count++;
            }
            if (count == 1){
                return distinct;
        }
        }
        }
        if (distinct == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return distinct;
    }




    public void addBefore(T input, T before){
        for (int i = 0; i<vals.length; i++){
            T temp = vals[i]; 
            if(temp.equals(before)){
                vals[i-1] = input; 

            }
        }
    }


    public void removeLast(T s){
        for (int i = vals.length; i>=0;i--){
            if (vals[i].equals(s)){
                vals[i] = vals[i+1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am working on the ArrayList implementation in Java. I have not been able to finish getUnique, removeLast and addBefore method. I can't seem to be working well with the arrays because I seem to have been replacing the values instead of adding it. A little help on what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In addBefore method you are rewritting content on index i-1 with your new varible, you are not adding it. You have to move the rest of the list one index to the right. Also try add new input before first element, it should crash.

In removeLast you are moving second to last variable to the last index (second to last = last). You should be just calling remove on last index.

I assume you want to return unique element in getUnique method. You are almost there, just look at the second for cycle. And btw you dont need help variable to save vals[i], you can just return vals[i].

Comment: This is not trivial, you will have to create new list where you add elements. First you will add these which are before the element you want to add, then you add the new one and then you add the rest of the list.

Comment: So you mean I will create a temp list and add it like this?

Comment: @STILL 

So, I did this 

public void addBefore(T input, T before){
  if(num == vals.length){
   T[] temp = (T[]) new Object[vals.length*2];
   T[] temp2 = (T[]) new Object[0];
   boolean check = false; 
   for(int i = 0; i<vals.length; i++){ 
    check = false; 
    
    if(vals[i].equals(before)){ 
     check = true; 
     temp[i] = input;
     
     break; 
    }
    temp[i] = vals[i];


   }   
 
  }
 }

How do I merge it now ?

Comment: So basically you now have temp which contains everything before the new input and the input itself. Now you just have to add to this temp all remaining elements. As a tip you can use the the same for cycle, you dont have to break from it (next element will have i+1 index). By the way, isnt this method suppose to have second parameter index of element where you should add new element? Because the way it is now the "before" element can be there multiple times (add before all these elements?).

Comment: And please next time edit your question with a code, its unreadable this way.